# why gameobject / raycast when dragged is not accurately following the touch position in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I made a script for multitouch using raycast. when dragged faster, the gameobject will be released, but when moving the gameobject slowly it follows the touch. here the codes

```
Vector2[] startPos = new Vector2[5];
Touch[] touch = new Touch[5];// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{

    Debug.Log(Input.touchCount);
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        touch[Input.touchCount-1] = Input.GetTouch(Input.touchCount-1);
        Vector2 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch[Input.touchCount-1].position);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(worldPoint, Vector2.zero, Mathf.Infinity);

        if (hit.transform != null)
        {
            if (touch[Input.touchCount - 1].phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                hit.transform.position = worldPoint;]
            }

            else if (touch[Input.touchCount-1].phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                startPos[touch[Input.touchCount-1].fingerId] = worldPoint;
            }

            else if (touch[Input.touchCount-1].phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                hit.transform.position = startPos[touch[Input.touchCount-1].fingerId];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

what can i do for drag faster without gameobject will released? sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

one solution is to play with a bool variable and tag,

you keep in memory the gameobject you are dragging, you set a bool variable to true.. this is the idea , you try to use bool variable instead touchphase.ended/began...

this [post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1333548/when-touch-and-drag-objects-in-android-fast-leave.html) could help you

i have just adapted to game2D

```
 GameObject objet = null;
 Plane plane;
 float rayDistance;
 Vector3 Offset;
 bool mouseOver = false;
 bool mousePressed = false;

void FixedUpdate()
{

    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        mousePressed = true;
    }
    else
    {
        mousePressed = false;
        objet = null;
    }

    Vector2 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch[Input.touchCount - 1].position);
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(worldPoint, Vector2.zero, Mathf.Infinity);

    if (hit.transform != null && hit.collider.tag == "Draggable")
    {
        mouseOver = true;
        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase != TouchPhase.Moved)
            objet = hit.collider.gameObject;
    }
    else
    {
        if (mousePressed == false)
            mouseOver = false;
    }

    if (mouseOver)
    {
        if (mousePressed)
        {
            //to adapt following your game configuration
            plane = new Plane(Camera.main.transform.forward * -1, objet.transform.position);
            plane.Raycast(ray, out rayDistance);
            objet.transform.position = ray.GetPoint(rayDistance);// + Offset; to see if offset is needed
        }
    }

} // end update
```